# Automate SFTP login using both key and password

Tags: linux, rsa, sftp, openssh

Recently SFTP hosted servers are enabled with two factor authentication. For details please refer the [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/193198/how-can-i-enable-both-password-and-public-key-authentication-with-openssh) here.

Now, we have requirement to automate this setup using command line. I found that as two different options for doing this:

```
 sshpass -p password sftp -oBatchMode=no -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no username@server1

 sftp -oIdentityFile=/path/to/private/key/file -oBatchMode=no -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no username@server1
```

But now I need to combine these two into single command and use it in my script for automating this sftp flow.

So, at first I need to send the private key file in the command line and then send the password in the same command line. I tried few options but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

How hard can it be to put both lines together:

```
sshpass -p password sftp -oBatchMode=no -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -oIdentityFile=/path/to/private/key/file username@server1
```

`ssh` itself will take care of both authentication methods.

Comment: I have already tried that and this doesn't work. The SFTP server just says "Authenticated with partial success." and doesn't provide the sftp prompt. Any other solution pls?

Comment: post the verbose log from the attempt (with `-vvv` switches to `sftp`).

Comment: While I realize this is an old issue, this approach worked for me.

Comment: @MikeNishizawa Thats what we have votes for here.